# User defined function in VBA not working and returns zero, no data type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, udf

I'm defining a user defined function as follows, when I am trying to call it in a subroutine, it returns a "zero" value, which surely is wrong.

```
Function Getpartialderiv_K_x(x As Variant, y As Variant, P As Variant, 
T As Variant, hx As Variant, dx As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Integer
ReDim dx(1 To UBound(x, 1)) As Variant

'record the original value for x
Dim original_x As Variant
original_x = x

'calc f(x+1)
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
x(i) = original_x(i) + dx(i)
Next i
Dim f1 As Variant
f1 = ThermoRel(x, y, P, T)

'calc f(x-1)
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
x(i) = original_x(i) - dx(i)
Next i
Dim f2 As Variant
f2 = ThermoRel(x, y, P, T)

'calc partial deriv
ReDim pderiv(1 To UBound(x, 1))
'get the results of partial derivatives
For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
pderiv(i) = (f1(i) - f2(i)) / (2 * hx)
Next i

Getpartialderiv_K_x = pderiv

End Function

Sub click2()

ReDim x(1 To 3) As Variant
ReDim y(1 To 3) As Variant
x = Array(0.4, 0.3, 0.3)
y = Array(0.3, 0.2, 0.5)
Dim P As Variant
P = 1171.904923  'pressure in the unit of psia
Dim T As Variant
T = 527.67 'fix temperature in the unit of oR
Dim hx As Variant
hx = 0.001
ReDim dx(1 To 3) As Variant
dx = Array(hx, 0, 0)

Dim result As Variant
result = Getpartialderiv_K_x(x, y, P, T, hx, dx)

MsgBox (result(1))

End Sub
```

However, when I was trying to duplicate the same code defining the above function using a subroutine, and providing the same input values, the results are totally OK, as follows:

```
Sub click()
Dim i As Integer
ReDim x(1 To 3) As Variant
ReDim y(1 To 3) As Variant
x = Array(0.4, 0.3, 0.3)
y = Array(0.3, 0.2, 0.5)
Dim P As Variant
P = 1171.904923  'pressure in the unit of psia
Dim T As Variant
T = 527.67 'fix temperature in the unit of oR
Dim hx As Variant
hx = 0.001
ReDim dx(1 To 3) As Variant
dx = Array(hx, 0, 0)

Dim original_x As Variant
original_x = x

'calc f(x + 1)
 For i = 1 To 3
 x(i) = original_x(i) + dx(i)
 Next i
 Dim f1 As Variant
 f1 = ThermoRel(x, y, P, T)

 'calc f(x - 1)
 For i = 1 To 3
 x(i) = original_x(i) - dx(i)
 Next i
 Dim f2 As Variant
 f2 = ThermoRel(x, y, P, T)

 ReDim pderiv(1 To 3) As Variant
 For i = 1 To 3
 pderiv(i) = (f1(i) - f2(i)) / (2 * hx)
 Next i

 Msgbox(pderiv(3))

 End Sub
```

I have checked the data type and it seems there is no mismatch. And also, the function ThermoRel(x, y, P, T) works fine and has a variant data type.
I have spent a lot of time and tried every way I can think of but still cannot figure it out, your inputs would be highly appreciated!!!

In order for you to easily debug it, I made a virtual example with the same errors (outputs zero) as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Function ThermoRel2(x As Variant, y As Variant, P As Variant, T As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Integer       'component index
Dim Ke As Variant      'equilibrium constant for each component
Ke = Array(0.8789, 1.0389, 0.7903)
ReDim outvec(LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)) As Variant

For i = LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)
outvec(i) = y(i) - x(i) * Ke(i)
Next i

ThermoRel2 = outvec

End Function

Function Getpartialderiv_K_x_2(x As Variant, y As Variant, P As Variant, T  As Variant, hx As Variant, dx As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Integer
ReDim dx(LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)) As Variant

'record the original value for x
Dim original_x As Variant
original_x = x

'calc f(x+1)
For i = LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)
x(i) = original_x(i) + dx(i)
Next i
Dim f1 As Variant
f1 = ThermoRel2(x, y, P, T)

'calc f(x-1)
For i = LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)
x(i) = original_x(i) - dx(i)
Next i
Dim f2 As Variant
f2 = ThermoRel2(x, y, P, T)

'calc partial deriv
ReDim pderiv(LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1))
'get the results of partial derivatives
For i = LBound(x, 1) To UBound(x, 1)
pderiv(i) = (f1(i) - f2(i)) / (2 * hx)
Next i

Getpartialderiv_K_x_2 = pderiv

End Function

Sub dbg()

Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant
ReDim x(1 To 3) As Variant
ReDim y(1 To 3) As Variant
x = Array(0.4, 0.3, 0.3)
y = Array(0.3, 0.2, 0.5)
Dim P As Variant
P = 1171.904923  'pressure in the unit of psia
Dim T As Variant
T = 527.67 'fix temperature in the unit of oR
Dim hx As Variant
hx = 0.001
Dim dx As Variant
ReDim dx(1 To 3) As Variant
dx = Array(hx, 0, 0)
Dim result As Variant
result = Getpartialderiv_K_x_2(x, y, P, T, hx, dx)
MsgBox (result(1))
End Sub
```

Thank you all for the help! I found in the locals window that the dx array becomes all zero after the function is called, which should be (hx, 0, 0). Out of some reason, the dx array is enforced to all zero, I don't know why...

Comment: It is a little difficult to debug without ThermoRel. No way for us to step through the code.

Comment: What have you done to debug it? For functions it is useful to put a break point right before the return and then inspect the values in the locals window. As Excel Hero says, it is hard to debug (and not really the job of Stack Overflow anyway) given what you have shown. My hunch is that some sort of byRef vs byVal problem is behind this all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have tried to put the values in the locals window, but I didn't put a break point right before the return, and all the values seem empty. The code defining the function ThermoRel is very long and has other functions related, so I didn't put it here.

Comment: I made a virtual example...

Comment: What are you doing with `dx` ?  You populate it in `dbg` and pass it to `Getpartialderiv_K_x_2` but there you immediately clear it out by using `Redim` without `Preserve`.  Do you mean to do that?

Comment: dx is an array used as one input argument for the function Getpartialderiv_K_x_2. In the sub dbg, I passed (0.001, 0, 0) to it, but it turns out to all zero. Do you mean I should add "preserve" before redim dx to avoid clearing it?

Comment: If you want to resize an existing array then you must use `ReDim Preserve` and not just `ReDim`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be your use of `Array()` to populate (eg) `x`
By using that you're re-defining the bounds:

```
Dim x()

ReDim x(1 To 3) As Variant

Debug.Print LBound(x), UBound(x) '<< 1, 3

x = Array(0.4, 0.3, 0.3)

Debug.Print LBound(x), UBound(x) '<< 0, 2
```

Comment: In the function, x is defined to be a vector whose highest subscript is dependent on the input vector. Does that mean I cannot use array() to populate x vector? Can I assign values to the elements of the vector "x" one by one? Like x(1) = 0.4, x(2) = 0.3, x(3)=0.3, or is there any more efficient way to assign the vector values? Thanks so much!

Comment: In your function you're looping over the array but starting with 1, so missing the zero'th element output from Array(). If you start with lbound(x) instead then you'd likely be ok

Comment: I started Lbound(x) in all my for loop, but the function still outputs zero results. In order for you to easily debug it, I made a virtual example with the same errors.

Comment: In your new piece of code you've used `Option Base 1` which wasn't visible before: if you're using that then `Array(...)` will indeed produce a 1-based array and not a zero-based as I wrote.  This is one good reason to **not** use `Option Base 1`: it makes your code behave differently from the "natural" VBA array behavior, which makes it difficult for others to debug your code.  Better to get used to 0-based arrays...

Comment: Yeah, I also found that the total number of indices has been 4 instead of 3, due to that array has the zeroth element.